# problema ao executar select em mais de uma tabela no delphi e firebird

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird

select funciona no firebird, porem da erro -104 no delphi

```
IBQuery2.SQL.Add('select l.jb_cdempresa, l.jb_cdfilial, p.dtvencimento, l.jb_cdcontacredito, p.vlrpago,');
        IBQuery2.SQL.Add('l.jb_cdcontacredito, p.vlrpago, f.cnpj_cpf, f.insc_rg,l.cnpj, l.insc,');
        IBQuery2.SQL.Add('from ctaspagar p, lojas l, fornecedores f');
        IBQuery2.SQL.Add('where p.cdloja = l.cdloja');
        IBQuery2.SQL.Add('  and f.cdfornecedor = p.cdfornecedor');
        IBQuery2.SQL.Add('  and p.cdloja = '+(EdLoja.Text)+'');
        IBQuery2.SQL.Add('and p.dtlancamento between :Data_Inicial and :Data_Final');

    IBQuery2.ParamByName('Data_Inicial').Value:= strtoDate(EdDataIni.Text);
    IBQuery2.ParamByName('Data_Final').Value:= strtoDate(EdDataIni.Text);
```

Comment: O problema deve estar na informação que esta chegando ao Parâmetro. Lembre-se de avaliar as respostas. Na sua outra pergunta não ouve avaliação, isto é importante para futuros pesquisadores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema pode estar na atribuição do parâmetro de data.
No Firebird o padrão de data é `mm/dd/yyyy` então...

```
IBQuery2.ParamByName('Data_Inicial').Value:= FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy', strtoDate(EdDataIni.Text));
IBQuery2.ParamByName('Data_Final').Value:= FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy', strtoDate(EdDataIni.Text));
```

Lembre-se que esta data deve estar entre aspas simples, logo o parâmetro deve receber:

```
QuotedStr(FormatDateTime(...
```